# A melancholic children's film set in a sandy landscape

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember any of the plot, only two scenes, and mostly how it made me feel.

I think I saw the film in the late 1980s or early 1990s on some German children's TV programme. Whether the original language was German or it was a dub I don't remember. I'm pretty sure it was a stand-alone film, but it could also have been a part of a series. I don't know if it was old or new at that time.

I remember two scenes that were set in a desert area, or a sandy landscape. In one scene there was a sweaty middle-aged man who operated a rusty, squeaky merry-go-round in the desert. In another scene a boy was building a rocket out of rusty metal scrap. At some point there was a lot of white smoke coming out of the rocket.

I think it was set in the present day.

The tone of the film was melancholic, thoughtful, and reflective. It gave me that feeling of melancholy you get when you wander around in abandoned industrial ruins with old rusty machines.

I remember the dialogue being slow and sparse. The film had eerie, weird music.

I think I once posted this question to some story identification forum some 10 years ago without getting any answers, but I'm not sure. It could also be that I just composed the question and never posted it.

Comment: *"I don't think it was science fiction, it was set in the present day."* Then it's probably off-topic here.

Comment: Building a rocket out of scrap metal in the desert, that appears to at least in some way, work? Sounds like science fiction elements to me.